# Hide slide controls if slider length < 2

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I've got this slider, and I want to hide its controls if it only has one element inside it.

**Markup:**

```
<div class="grid carousel-controls">
    <span class="control prev"></span>
    <span class="control next"></span>
</div>

<div class="carousel">
    <img src="//placecage.com/440/660"/>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function(){
    var count = $('.carousel').children().length;

    if (count < 2) {
        $('.carousel-controls').hide();
    }
});
```

Any takers? ❤️

**Edit:** Worth adding that it's inside a tab nav, wherein the other carousel has > 2 children, in which case I obviously want the controls to be visible.

Comment: maybe make a snippet of it or a fiddle so we can visualise it

Comment: you mean you have two or more tabs and each tab has its own carousel?

Comment: @Dinesh Yes, sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

```
$(function(){
 $('.carousel').each(function(i, c){
     var count = $(c).children().length;

     // if the .carousel-controls is a children of .carousel
     if (count < 3)
         $(c).find('.carousel-controls').hide();

     // if the .carousel-controls is a siblings of .carousel
     if (count < 2)
         $(c).siblings('.carousel-controls').hide();

     // comment out the inappropriate syntax above.


 });
});
```

`find()` is relative to `.carousel` and depends where `.carousel-controls` is placed. If `.carousel-controls` is inside `.carousel`, it would also be consider a *children* of `.carousel` so you need to count less than 3.

Comment: `.carousel-controls` is a sibling of `.carousel`. Will there be any change to the code in that case?

Comment: @AronHøyer are all the carousel content (leaving controls) image file? Because the above code is also counting `.carousel-controls`. If all are images, `var count = $(c).find('img').length` else if there are many other things apart from images which are not hold under a particular div, you may try, `if (count < 3)` consider the `.carousel-controls` is also a children of `.carousel`

Comment: @AronHøyer If the `.carousel-controls` is a sibling of `.carousel`, then the code replace `find()` with `siblings()`, i.e. `$(c).siblings('.carousel-controls').hide();`

Comment: However, if I change the code such that `.carousel-control` is `display: none;` by default, and in jQuery hide them when `$(count > 1)`, it doesn't work anymore. For me, this seems more expedient.

Comment: Never mind. Stylesheet overwrote the JS. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you an idea.

Assumption: only one tab will be active at a time

find carousel-controls of active tab only. and then you can controls hide them based on logic.

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', function (e) {

    // access carousel here then you can find children here using $(this); 
    // your logic goes here.  
 });
```

This piece of code is for reference only.